# Why doesn't my kitten poop?

Tags: cats

I have a two-week-old kitten. I adopted him at one week old. He took his first poop in the first week and since then (something like 3-4 days) he hasn't had another one. I am reading a lot about kittens and doing exactly everything according to the instructions (amount of food, body temperature, and stimulation).

The strange thing is that he seems to be in good health and doesn't show signs of uncomfortableness. He also has a normal appetite and he urinates normally.

In the first week when he had the poop, he was fed with some non-famous kitten formula the first day but then I was told that it could be dangerous (although this food should be fine) so I bought him Royal Canin and he is eating only this food since then. I thought maybe to give him the previous food and see if it would help him poop but I was afraid to try. This food is from Petex company and it should be completely fine but some cat people scared me that I should only use Royal Canin.

Is there anything that I should be aware of that can cause it or that can help him that I might have missed?

Edit: he got enema and now he is fine

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! In general one should visit a vet if cats chabge their behaviour. Maybe you can find a real person who cared for very young kittens and has experience to show and share with you. A call/visit with a vet would be also a good idea in general.

Comment: I am surprised a 2 week kitten has been removed from mom.  Even more surprised at 1 week. The cats I have had I have left with mom until mom started to push them away, usually six weeks or more.  Anyway, as @Allerleirauh said, I hope you have talked to a veterinarian.

Comment: At two weeks, this is considered a neonatal kitten, which requires specialized care (including feeding formula every couple of hours and stimulating them to relieve themselves. You need to use specialized guides for neonatal kittens (The Kitten Lady is a good resource); you can't just toss it some kibble and hope for the best.

Comment: If you would actually read what I wrote you would realize that I am aware of that